# Not able to shift from a specific gear

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear, shifting

I have a 9-speed rear derailleur and shifting from 1 to 9 isn’t a problem except when it is from 6 to 7, while downshifting has a bit of lag, upshifting takes forever and sometimes it doesn’t even shift. I have noticed this problem since I bought the bike and the shifting has only gotten worse specifically 6-7. I have tried adjusting the barrel adjustor, cable tension, limit screws etc but nothing seems to work

Bike: Scott subcross 30

Rear derailleur: Shimano Alivio

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there damage?   This smells like a bent hanger.   Did you buy the bike new or used ?

Comment: No damage, the hanger isn’t bent, bought it new

Comment: Still sounds like RD to be adjusted properly, perhaps with a more methodical approach. Limit screws don't do anything in the middle of the cassette and would terminally prevent a shift if screwed in too much. The fact that shifting got worse is probably just the regular wear-in/bedding in of the cables on a new bike - check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkZxPIZ1ngY&t=8s

Comment: I did some more adjustments and the shifting has gotten better, what I have noticed is that the gear shifts perfectly from 6 to 7 at a specific speed